# External SD Card removed - Apps can't be deinstalled :-(

Tags: google-play-store, external-sd, uninstallation

My external SD card seems to be broken. I removed it and inserted a new one.

Now the apps don't work any more. That's all right.

But: I can't uninstall or re-install the apps any more.

If I try to, then the app store seems to crash. I just get the message "App store terminated" (translated from german to english).

It's ok that the data from the sd card is lost.

But: How to get the apps working again?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling them via *Settings › Apps* (the internal app manager)? Another option would be using `adb uninstall` (from your computer, if you've installed ADB stuff) or `pm uninstall` (from a terminal app, most likely requires root).

Comment: Yes, I have tried to uninstall via "Settings › Apps". I don't know what `adb uninstall` is.

Comment: If you don't know what ADB is, it's unlikely you have it installed (for a short intro, please see our [adb tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) and [ADB for end-users](http://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/adb-for-end-users) – it's a very useful tool, I wouldn't know what to do without ;) So have you tried `pm uninstall` (requires the app's package name as parameter, e.g. `pm uninstall com.foobar.app`)? Did it work? Is your device rooted?

Comment: @Izzy, not the device is not rooted. Does adb work without root access?

Comment: Yes, the ADB daemon runs with enhanced privileges, so `adb uninstall com.foobar.app` should work. To avoid unnecessary large installs, you could take a look at [my answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/42475/16575 "Is there a minimal installation of ADB?") for a minimal installation.